# REGEXTRACT - to match one letter represented by a special character within a string

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm facing a little problem to do the following:

I have within cells (in Google sheets) some text, and I'm searching to extract what's after Question 1: More precisely, the missing letter represented by the special character ●

The cell might contains one of the following strings:

Question 1: ●BCD

Question 1: A●CD

Question 1: AB●D

Question 1: ABC●

The letters extracted can only be (A,B,C,D) in capital, so in the first example, I should extract the letter A, in the second the letter B, in the third the letter C, and in the last example the letter D.

After searching for a while I was able to write the following:

```
=IFERROR(trim(upper(regexextract(trim(clean(substitute(B2,char(160)," "))),"Question 1:(\s?[a-dA-D])"))),"??")
```

But this extract always the letter A, and if the special character is at the beginning (example 1) I get an error.

Another similar scenario is again to extract the letters T or F in the following:

Question 2 : ●F  (here we should extract T)

Question 2 : T●  (here we should extract F)

Thank you for showing some lights on these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(B2, CHAR(10)), "Question \d+: ", "♦")), 
 "where Col1 contains '♦'"), "♦", )), 
 {"BCD",  "A";
  "A CD", "B";
  "AB D", "C";
  "ABC",  "D";
  "F",    "T";
  "T",    "F"}, 2, 0))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank a lot player0 you were able to solve my problem in few clicks only. That's amazing!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex to achieve this. See the following example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iMt0pUeyenIAzdHAw2f5jhT41B-Tz86Ab3YfZgXhKk0/edit#gid=0

Question 1 formula:

```
=MID("ABCD", FIND("●", A2) - FIND(":", A2) - 1, 1)
```

Question 2 formula:

```
=MID("TF", FIND("●", A6) - FIND(":", A6) - 1, 1)
```

The linked sheet breaks down procedurally how you can arrive at this by:

1. Finding the position of the character you are looking for `FIND("●", A2)` in the original text
2. Converting that to a relative position `<position> - FIND(":", A2) - 1`
3. Returning the character at the specific position `MID("ABCD", <relative position>, 1)`

Comment: Thank you for help, I don't know If I was not clear in my question when I said 'The cell might contains', I meant that there is some text before 'Question 1: ●BCD' and there is some text after it. Something like that: Text Text Text Question 1: ●BCD Question 2: A●CD Question 3: AB●D Question 4: ABC● Text Text Question 5: T● Question 6: ●F Text Text. If the Arrayformula is used I need to transpose the results horizontally, as I'm aim to extract the letter for each question in a different cell, otherwise I'll have to copy the formula as many times needed, which is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(CHAR(FINDB("●", A1:A)-FINDB(":", A1:A)+63)))
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(CHAR(FINDB("●", A1:A)-LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "(.+: )"))+64)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(CHAR(FINDB("●", A1:A)-FINDB(":", A1:A)+82)), "U", "F"))
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(CHAR(FINDB("●", A1:A)-
 LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "(.+: )"))+83)), "U", "F"))
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

> I need to transpose the results horizontally, as I'm aiming to extract the letter for each question in a different cell

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "T●|●F"), 
 SUBSTITUTE(CHAR(FIND("●", A2:A)-FIND(":", A2:A)+82), "U", "F"), 
            CHAR(FIND("●", A2:A)-FIND(":", A2:A)+63))), COUNTA(A2:A), 1)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for help, I don't know If I was not clear in my question when I said 'The cell might contains', I meant that there is some text before 'Question 1: ●BCD' and there is some text after it. Something like that: Text Text Text Question 1: ●BCD Question 2: A●CD Question 3: AB●D Question 4: ABC● Text Text Question 5: T● Question 6: ●F Text Text. If  the `Arrayformula` is used I need to transpose the results horizontally, as I'm aim to extract the letter for each question in a different cell, otherwise I'll have to copy the formula as many times needed, which is not a problem.

Comment: did you even try suggested formulas? is question with ABCD in the same column as question with TF ?? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9faJT.png

Comment: Yes I did, but maybe to have a clear picture of the situation, I'll share a demo spreadsheet to show what I'm trying to do exactly for each question: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lIh1_Xv7LEukhXBH0II0HyZCP-h0OrVZ-PK5YRXo87c/edit?usp=sharing) Thank you for your support